# Optimize Piwik CPU performance: Apache module configuration?

Tags: php, matomo

I have my own install of Piwik on a Apache server. I get more and more CPU alerts because of the PHP (5.4) processes.

Are there specific modules I could add to Apache in order to minimize Piwik CPU resources?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with php-fpm?

For sites with high traffic, I'd recommend using Nginx instead of Apache. Please see [this FAQ](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to-install/#faq_116).